# Prove that $ \varphi_t* f(x)\to f(x)\;\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;t\to0 $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, convolution

Let $\varphi\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ and positive, such that $\int_{\Bbb R^n}\varphi=1$.

Then set $$\varphi_t(x):=\frac1{t^n}\varphi(x/t)$$ for $t>0$; in such a way, $\varphi_t$ has the same properties of $\varphi$.

> I have to prove that
>   $$
> \varphi_t* f(x)\to f(x)\;\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;t\to0
> $$
>   for every $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$, with $1\le p<\infty$.

There was a hint, which suggested to approximate $f$ by taking a $g$ continous with compact support such that $||f-g||_p<\varepsilon$ and next writing
\begin{align*}
|\varphi_t* f(x)-f(x)|
&\le |\varphi_t* (f-g)(x)|+|\varphi_t* g(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-f(x)|
\end{align*}
Now we know that second summand goes to $0$ as $t\to0$, by the regularity and boundedness of $g$.

For the third summand: since we are checking pointwise convergence, once we fixed $x\in\Bbb R^n$, we can take $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$, so the third summand vanish: is this correct?

The problem comes from the first summand; it is controlled by
$$
M(f-g)(x):=\sup_{r>0}\frac1{|B(x,r[|}\int_{B(x,r[}|f(y)-g(y)|\,dy
$$
this is not trivial: let's accept this.
We know that $M$ is an operator bounded on $L^p$, but how can we deduce from this a bound which is small as we want (exploiting the $\varepsilon$ distance in the $p$-norm)?

Comment: You can try something like this. Let $\epsilon>0$, $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ and $g$ continuous with compact support such that $\|f-g\|_p<\varepsilon/2$.
We have
\begin{align*}{
\phi_t* f(x)- f(x) =\\
\int_{\Bbb R^n} \phi_t(y)f(x-y)dy-\int_{\Bbb R^n} \phi_t(y)f(x)dy =\\ 
\int_{\Bbb R^n} \phi_t(y)[f(x-y)-g(x-y)+g(x-y)-g(x)+g(x)-f(x)]dy
}\end{align*} Moreover, $g$ is uniformly continuous on its compact support.

Comment: You have $\varphi_t(x):=\frac1{t^n}\varphi(x/t)$. Where does the $n$ in $t^n$ come in?

Comment: The functions live in $\Bbb R^n$; the $\frac1{t^n}$ is the correct scaling factor to ensure that $\int \phi_t = 1$.

Comment: @martycohen guys thanks for the suggestions, but I can't use them to get a way to solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure you are asking for *pointwise* convergence, when $f\in L^p$ is only defined almost everywhere?

Comment: I think the answer is: mimic the proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. If you have the same sort of bounds for the weak-$L^1$ or $L^p$ norm of the $\varphi$-maximal function $x \mapsto \sup_{t > 0} \lvert \varphi_t \ast f(x) \rvert$ as for the traditional maximal function $M$, then the proof should work.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to obtain $L^p$ convergence, not pointwise which wouldn't make sense for an $L^p$ function anyway. Assuming the result for $f\in C^0$ as you have and using the hint to choose $g∈ C^0$ with $‖f-g‖_{L^p} < ε$, 
$$ ‖\phi_t * f - f‖_{L^p} \leq ‖\phi_t *(f - g)‖_{L^p} + ‖ \phi_t * g - g ‖_{L^p} + ‖f-g‖_{L^p} $$
The second and third terms are OK; the second because I assumed you can do it, and the third is by the choice of $g$. $M$ being a bounded operator $L^p → L^p$ means that for some $C>0$,
$$ ‖Mf‖_{L^p} \leq C‖f‖_{L^p}$$
Just apply this to $M(f-g)$ to get (by our assumption $f-g∈ L^p$)
$$ ‖M(f-g)‖_{L^p} \leq C‖f-g‖_{L^p} \leq Cε $$
Which is enough because we have the a.e. control $|\phi_t * (f-g)| \leq M(f-g)$.

As @EricThoma said in the comments, if you know the Young's inequality for convolutions $\|f*g‖_{L^p} \leq ‖f‖_{L^1} ‖g‖_{L^p}$ then you don't ned to worry about maximal functions. There's a proof [here.](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~banuelos/ma544-05/lectures3.pdf)

Comment: Pointwise almost everywhere makes sense. Also, $L^p$ convergence is immediate from Young's inequality for convolutions. I do think that pointwise almost everywhere convergence is false however.

Comment: @EricThoma you're not wrong but I went with the hint and also tried to push OP in that direction. I don't know the full answer for a.e. convergence, but if the maximal operator $T^* = \sup_t |T_t(·)|$ is weak $(p,q)$ for some $q$, then $T_t f → f$ a.e. A sufficient condition for this is for the function $\phi$ to be radial and decreasing.